# Reverse Engineering Crystal Reports Definition Files

Tags: crystal-reports

We're creating a metamodel of our report definitions within our central metadata repository.  We know how to "harvest" SSRS reports since they are XML.  IS there any easy way to do the same for Crystal Reports.  We're interested in getting to anything CR understands about the report (similar in concept to the SSRS RDL Model)

TIA,
Paolo

Answer (score 6):

Use the Crystal Reports SDK (Java or .Net version) to convert the object hierarchy to an XML representation.

Samples:

- Visual Basic .Net:  [RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)
- C# .Net: [RptToXml](https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml)
- PowerShell: [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal)

Comment: RptToXml works nicely for diff-comparing, among other things.

Comment: I know RptToXml is neat for diff-comparing. Is there anyway to convert from the xml back to rpt though?

Answer (score 4):

You can get a report definition text file if you export the crystal report as...you guessed it "Report Definition(TXT)" It has the crystal version and lots of info for each section such as datafields, formatting, etc...

Comment: My Crystal Reports 2016 unceremoniously crashes when I try to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://www.reportminer.com/, it includes a diff tool (although after exporting to text you can use the diff'er of your choice).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this.  CR files are in a closed and proprietary format.  :-(

Comment: I created an 'idea' on SAP's site about this.  Please vote for it and add your comments.  https://cw.sdn.sap.com/cw/ideas/12337

Comment: RptToXml will dump RPT files to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this once to debug a Crystal problems, it might help:

[rpt Inspector](http://crystal-enterprise-tool.qarchive.org/)

Answer (score 0):

RptToRdl.Com [(http://www.RptToRdl.com)](http://www.rpttordl.com) will do this for you for $25. Check out their FAQ, and you can get one done for free.