# Crystal reports 2011 list tables in footer

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal reports 2011 standalone. Is it possible to list the tables used within a report in the footer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You could use the Crystal Reports SDK to extract the report's metadata and store it in a table, however.  See: [Reverse Engineering Crystal Reports Definition Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332787/reverse-engineering-crystal-reports-definition-files)

Comment: Thanks! We'll just leave the table names out.